# Karate:How to make data initialization only execute once

Tags: automated-tests, karate, bdd, data-driven-tests

In this feature file, the @setup Scenario will run twice due to there are two other scenarios outline use it
Feature:

@setup
Scenario:

def data = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]
Scenario Outline: row

print 'a: ', a

Examples:
| karate.setup().data |

Scenario Outline: test row

- print 'test a: ', a

Examples:
| karate.setup().data |

how to make the Scenario with @setup only run once?

I want make the Scenario with @setup only run once.

[image]

Comment: use the `once` keyword in the Scenario Outline. This keyword can be used to ensure that a particular set of steps is only executed once in a given test run

Comment: How to  use the once keyword?

Answer (score 1):

in 1.3.1 version
Feature:

@setup
Scenario:

- def fun = function(){ karate.log('function executed'); return [{a: 1}, {a: 2}] }
- def data = callonce fun

Scenario Outline:

- print 'second:', __row
  Examples:
  | karate.setupOnce().data |

Comment: should karate.setupOnce() be used only within "Examples" section?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: after this question, we decided to add the option to `karate.setupOnce()` that achieves this in a more elegant way: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2210

Here is your solution. You can run it and see for yourself.

```
Feature:

@setup
Scenario:
* def fun = function(){ karate.log('function executed'); return [{a: 1}, {a: 2}] }
* def data = callonce fun

Scenario Outline:
* print 'first:', __row

Examples:
| karate.setup().data |

Scenario Outline:
* print 'second:', __row
    
Examples:
| karate.setup().data |
```

Comment: the @setup  still run twice  as the picture said.

Comment: @lovelemon you are right, we can improve this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2210